# Binary XML file line #75: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

when i insert the scroll view tag in xml its gives these errors.

Binary XML file line #75: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
07-03 10:20:41.639: E/AndroidRuntime(21308):

"scrollView1" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"scrollView1" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"

****xml** **

```
<TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

           <ScrollView
               android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/list"
               android:background="#ffffff"
               android:fadingEdge="none"
               android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="#343534"
                 android:padding="8dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SIP Account  Settings"
        android:textSize="18dip" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

     </TableRow>



 <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/one"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/selector"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:onClick="rowClick" >

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="User Name"
                  android:textSize="20sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>



 <TableRow   
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:onClick="rowClick"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"

        android:focusable="true">

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Display Name "
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>


 <TableRow   
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:onClick="rowClick"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"

        android:focusable="true">

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Auth Login" 
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>


 <TableRow   
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:onClick="rowClick"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"

        android:focusable="true">

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Auth Password" 
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>



        <TableRow

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:background="#0E76BC">

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dip"
                    android:text="Other Settings"
                    android:textSize="18dip" 
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:background="#0E76BC" 
                    android:textColor="#0E76BC" 
                    android:padding="8dip"/>
            </TableRow>


 <TableRow   
        android:id="@+id/fivee"
        android:onClick="rowClick"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"

        android:focusable="true">




        </TableRow>


                <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow111"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#343534" android:padding="8dip">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Domain Settings"

                    android:textSize="18dip" 
                    android:textStyle="bold" 
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
            </TableRow>


 <TableRow   
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:onClick="rowClick"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"

        android:focusable="true">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter Domain :" 
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>


  <TableRow   
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:onClick="rowClick"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"

        android:focusable="true">

       <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enter Sip Proxy" 
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>


   <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
         android:id="@+id/local_port_sip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textStyle="bold"

         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Register To SIP Proxy" 
         android:textSize="20dip" android:textColor="#ffffff" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
                   android:layout_marginRight="40dip"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"

                    android:layout_width="325dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button" />

            </TableRow>

    </ScrollView>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

```
 <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/selector"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:onClick="rowClick" >
```

you are getting error because you can't supply width value in table row.

Comment: You've got `layout_height` twice.

Comment: same error but line num is change Binary XML file line #77: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

Comment: @user3136235 also supply height and widht  <TableRow   
        android:id="@+id/two"

Comment: check all the rows because you not supplying height and width on rows

Comment: ScrollView can host only one direct child
07-03 11:10:08.561: E/AndroidRuntime(2241at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:297)
07-03 11:10:08.561: E/AndroidRuntime(22419):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:743)
07-03 11:10:08.561: E/AndroidRuntime(22419):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
07-03 11:10:08.561: E/AndroidRuntime(22419):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
07-03 11:10:08.561: E/AndroidRuntime(22419):